# Не корректно отображаются русские символы

Tags: php, mysql

Есть такой код, кодировка стоит UTF-8, но символы русские отображаются не корректно, что нужно добавить?

```
<?php
$host='localhost'; // имя хоста
$database='arcana'; // имя базы данных
$user='root'; // заданное вами имя пользователя
$pswd=''; // пароль
$dbh = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pswd) or die("Не могу соединиться с MySQL.");
mysql_select_db($database) or die("Не могу подключиться к базе.");
$query = "SELECT * FROM `books`";
$res = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
echo "Номер: ".$row['title_book']."<br>\n";
echo "Email: ".$row['description_book']."<br>\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: Сам php сохраните как UTF8 для начала

Comment: он сохранен как utf8

Comment: вы имеете ввиду текст сообщений из php или sql ответа?

Comment: <?php header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); ?>

Comment: Используйте `charset` для установки кодировки результата sql запроса.